# Declaration syntax error in return type bool function

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 4

bool mazeUtil(int[N][N] maze,int x, int y, sol[N][N]);-->Compile time error at this line number.

    int main() {
      return 0;
    }
bool mazeUtil(int[][] maze,int x, int y,int[][] sol){
     if(isSafe){
          sol[x][y] = 1;
         if(mazeUtil(maze,x+1,y,sol)==true){
            return true;
          }
         if(mazeUtil(maze,x,y,sol)==true){
            return true;
           }
          sol[x][y]=0;
      }
      return false;
   }
```

**bool mazeUtil(int[N][N] maze,int x, int y, sol[N][N]);**

I declared this function unlikely they not find bool type but when I changed into different datatype function **void** it can be compiled without any error.

How can I use bool return type function ? Am I missed some header file? Would you please give a some insight on this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are arrays declared? How are multiple arguments of the same type declared? Perhaps you need to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over with some of the basics?

Comment: You might want `bool mazeUtil(int maze[N][N],int x, int y, int sol[N][N]);`.

Comment: try to code in `C++ish` way if you are tagging the problem with c++ tag. for use 2D vectors

Comment: I wonder who upvoted this question... Why do you say that the error is the "syntax error in return type bool function"?

Comment: @AlexLop. No I told it's "declaration syntax error" in the header of this question.

Comment: @songyuanyao Post it as an answer :)

Comment: @songyuanyao I tried in both way but same error :(

Comment: @QuokMoon [Demo](http://rextester.com/KVYQD84575)

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks a lot . :)

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help.:)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are going with `C` programming you will get `unknown type name ‘bool’` error. So `#include<stdbool.h>`.**

You have tagged the post as `C++`. For `C++` it should compile fine without the inclusion.

Moreover,

> Multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the
>   first.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 4

//SEE THIS LINE
bool mazeUtil(int maze[][N],int x, int y,int sol[][N]); 

    int main() {
      return 0;
    }

//SEE THIS LINE
bool mazeUtil(int maze[][N],int x, int y,int sol[][N]){ 

     if(isSafe){
          sol[x][y] = 1;
         if(mazeUtil(maze,x+1,y,sol)==true){
            return true;
          }
         if(mazeUtil(maze,x,y,sol)==true){
            return true;
           }
          sol[x][y]=0;
      }
      return false;
   }
```

Also `isSafe` is undeclared.